# Why is this element irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

I am following a proof that every PID $R$ is also UFD

The proof starts this way:

Define $$S := \{a \in R \setminus U(R) \mid a \neq 0 \land a \mathrm{\ is \ not \ a \ product \ of \ irreducible \ elements}\}$$

It then says: Because $R$ is Noetherian, it follows that the set $\{(a) \mid a \in S\}$ has a maximal element $(a)$ with $a \in S$. Clearly this element is reducible.

Why is this element reducible?

For me, a product is a binary operation, so if you want to say it is reducible, there should be a factorisation $a = bc$ where both $b,c$ are non-units.

Comment: What is $U(R)$? The units of $R$ (which I'd write $R^\times$)?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly that.

Comment: My definition of irreducible is that for any non invertible element that is non zero such that $a = bc$  we either have that b is a unit or c is a unit.

Comment: I suppose "not a product" here speaks not only products of two factors, but both more than two and less than two. In particular, if $a$ were irreducible, it would be a one-factor product.

Comment: Hmmm, so a 1 factor product is also a product you think? In that case the question is solved. Because then $a$ must be reducible trivially.

Comment: I suppose there's a typo in your question: it should be  $\{a\in R\setminus U(R)\mid ...$.

Comment: Ah yes, fixed it

Comment: Someone cares to explain the downvote?

Comment: Not me anyway. Never mind , there are some downvote maniacs on this site.

Comment: I just always ask so I can maybe improve the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, an irreducible element *is* considered a product of irreducible elements.

By assumption, $a$ is not a product of irreducible elements, so it is not irreducible (a one element product is allowed here).

Hence it is reducible.

Now the contradiction is easily reached, because $a=bc$ with neither $b$ nor $c$ invertible. Therefore $(a)\subsetneq(b)$ and $(a)\subsetneq(c)$. By maximality, both $b$ and $c$ are product of irreducible elements.